# _winreg.CreateKey problem in Python

Tags: python, windows, registry

I'm trying to create a key like this

```
_winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSCONFIG\\startupreg\\test\\')
```

and the key is beeing created here

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSCONFIG\startupreg\test\
```

why?

Yes, Windows 7 64x here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: ok, it's shared... but the msconfig isn't sharing.. how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the article Glenn referred to, but it will not be much help.

What you probably need is proper access rights combined with [access to the 64-bit registry view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
with _winreg.CreateKeyEx(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                             r"Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSCONFIG\startupreg\test\", 
                             0, 
                             _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY | _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key:

    _winreg.SetValueEx(key, "testValueName", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, "value")
```

Please note the combination of those `_winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY | _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS`.